# Windows crashing after upgrade/downgrade, possible hardware issue?

Tags: dell-inspiron

I'm working on a friend's 3 year old Dell Inspiron 15-3521 laptop which has not worked properly since he attempted to upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 10. After he completed the upgrade, he could not boot into Windows and would get 1 of 2 outcomes.

[image: Request an Automatic Repair]

or it would boot to a black screen that read

```
>>Start PXE over iPv4, Press: [ESC] to EXIT...
```

He tried to do the automatic repair and that also failed(not sure of the error).

After giving up for about a month, he gave it to me and asked me to put Windows 7 on it instead. Because I could not access the Windows installation, I booted into a Linux Mint Live USB and formatted the hard drive and ran 1 pass of memtest(which passed fine). I installed Windows 7(my personal legitimate copy) without much hassel and was able to boot into it. After about 5 minutes, it became unbearably slow to navigate so I rebooted. After rebooting, I am able to get to the login screen, but when I enter my credentials, the computer either restarts with no warning or freezes on a black screen.

I then thought the hard drive could be going out because 2 operating systems have failed on that drive but Mint runs fine from my USB so I booted back into Mint and checked the drive with these smartctl commands.

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.19.0-32-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

and

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 128
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1357
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       1989
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2120
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       630
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       13592
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 14/48)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       77013252
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       255813054
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       1940
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       13467984753
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20501446141
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

I'm not an expert, but it says that it passes?

So now I'm a little stumped. Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on? Thanks.

Comment: Try a new drive.

Comment: It sounds like its the drive.  Have you tried a new drive?

Comment: I don't have another drive to test with right now, but I can probably get one later. Is there anything else I can try or is this on hold until I can test a different drive?

Comment: I could have told you before you did the format, that the HDD was failing, if it was attempting to to even boot to a PXE drive.

Comment: Ah I see. Ok I'll try a new drive later to confirm. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Picked up a new drive and everything is running perfectly. That confirms that it was just a bad hard drive. Thank you